# Recurse through a dynamic array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, performance, recursion

I am looking for a generalised solution for the following snippet::

```js
var d = [[1,2,3], [1,2], [1,2,3,4,5,6]];

d[0].map((val1, index1) => {
    d[1].map((val2, index2) => {
        d[2].map((val3, index3) => {
            console.log(index1, index2, index3);
        })
    })
});
```

Here this consoles a possible combination for the 3 array elements.

Can we make it generalise, say e.g.

```
var d = [[1,2,3], [1,2], [1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4]]; // k number of elements
```

Psuedo code::

```
let processor = (d) => {
    // implementation code
    // output will be the combination for 4 array elements this time.
}
```

Can someone help me design the process function? Looking for a generalised solution.Any help or lead is appreciable.

Comment: Iterating over `d` and using `Array.isArray()` and calling the function recursively. For each element, it will `push` it to a resulting array.

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to accomplish, even in the specialized case...

Comment: are you trying to merge the array? Your question is not clear. Can u explain little more on what u trying to achieve?

Comment: This is not the usecase of `map` you may want to change it to `forEach`! Not a solution though!

Comment: This makes as much sense as a chocolate teapot. Please revise it

Comment: @ajaiJothi I am trying to compute the permutation of values. Check the log. So there are 3 arrays in the d variable. I am just trying to compute their combination.

Comment: what combination? A `set` of all numbers? The sum of all numbers? be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach.

```js
var d = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
    processor = array => {
        var iter = p => p.length < array.length ?
                array[p.length].forEach((_, i) => iter(p.concat(i))) :
                console.log(p);

        iter([]);
    };

processor(d);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows;

```js
var cart = (a,b) => a.reduce((p,c) => p.concat(b.map(e => [].concat(c,e))),[]);
     arr = [[1,2,3], [1,2], [1,2,3,4,5,6], [8,9]],
     res = arr.reduce(cart);

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: @georg It's a pity you deleted your answer. Honestly, i believe this job has to be done lazily by generators. But in JS they don't look as cool as they do in Haskell.